# Javascript addEventListener for keyup not registering any key values

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener, keyboard-events

I am calling function test() with a onload call from the body. Then in the test function I am calling keyPushed(e) but the code I have is not registering any keyValues. Furthermore the console is saying that my e value is not defined, not sure why it works in the example I got it from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml). What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<body onload="test()">

</body>
```

JS:

```
test = function(){
  console.log("test");
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyPushed(e));
}
keyPushed = function(e){
  var keyValue = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
  alert(keyValue);
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/QNWPwQ?editors=1010)

Comment: Pass the function itself by providing just its name – `addEventListener("keydown", keyPushed);`. With the additional parenthesis, you're invoking it one time immediately and at best passing its `return` value to `addEventListerner()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyPushed(e));
```

to

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyPushed);
```

you need register event handler with `addEventListener()` not call them directly